# How to control ESC (electronic speed controlling) using a micro controller.?

Tags: microcontroller, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I found on internet in some articles that only customized ESC's for brush less motors can be controlled with a micro controller not ESC's (ESC's for brush-less motors) that available in market. is that true? or there is no restrict of controlling a brush less motor speed using a micro controller with a ESC which available in market?

Comment: The ESC has to be a brushless motor ESC. Those designed for brushed motors won't work wit a brushless motor.

Comment: so there is no problem ? to control an ESC using a PIC or ARM micro controller ?just giving PPS according to theory will work fine for ESC's available in market?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking if off-the-shelf ESCs (Electronic Speed Controls) used in radio-control models for brushless motors can be easily controlled with a microcontroller. The answer is yes. You will need to provide a positive pulse whose width you can accurately control and adjust between 1 milliseconds (for minimum motor speed, or no rotation) to 2 milliseconds (for maximum motor speed). The pulse is 5 Volt logic level and repeats about every 20 milliseconds (rate is not very critical).

Here's a simple reference: http://www.endurance-rc.com/ppmtut.php

When you stop sending pulses (0 Volts), most ESCs will hold the last throttle setting for a little while and then turn off. This is done to filter out any glitches that the radio link might produce.

Also, there are ESCs that provide a reverse rotation and braking action (for RC cars). You will need to examine the manual to determine what type of pulse is needed to activate these functions.

Comment: This is basically correct, what keeps it from being complete is the fact that many ESCs have to be initialized by a sequence of throttle changes before they will activate.  For example you may have to have your program run the throttle PWM signal from minimum to maximum and back down to minimum.  Or you may just have to momentarily dwell at minimum - it really depends on the design and tuning of the ESC.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's true.  Many ESCs are just microcontrollers controlling a power stage with some sort of feedback (Hall sensors for example) for keeping the appropriate commutation angle.  So you can build your own ESC with a microcontroller, some interface parts and some power FETs for example.

The only restrictions on speed from either an off-the-shelf or custom built ESC are the design of the motor and ESC.  (Max rated speed of the motor, max voltage allowable on the ESC, max commutation speed, etc.)

Or maybe I'm missing the point of the question entirely.

Comment: I need to no whether i can control an ESC that available in market using a PIC , Arduino or an ARM micro controller ? or i have to design and build my own ESC?

Comment: Oh, OK, you need to look for an ESC that has appropriate inputs to interface with a microcontroller then.  Some have digital inputs, though you could conceivable control speed for example with a DAC output from a microcontroller connected to an analog speed input on an ESC.

Comment: i know that ESC has PPS signal input, GND and Power, so you meant that i can control speed brush-less motor with an ARM micro controller by just powering up and giving proper PPS value (pulses per second) .still i am talking about ESC's that available in market (just say ESC's sale on ebay).